# How can format date to French value in RobotFramework?

Tags: datetime, robotframework

Is it possible set a Local to [Convert Date](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Convert%20Date) in Robotframework?

```
${today}=    Get Time
${today_s}=  Convert Date  ${today}  result_format=%A %d %B
```

> Thursday 04 April

but i need

> Mardi 04 Avril

**EDIT with a workaround:**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    Collections

*** Variables ***
&{day_of_week_collections}  Monday=Lundi  Thursday=Mardi  Wednesday=Mercredi  Thursday=Jeudi  Friday=Vendredi  Saturday=Samedi  Sunday=Dimanche
&{month_collections}        January=Janvier  February=Février  March=Mars  April=Avril  May=Mai  June=Juin  July=Juillet  August=Août  September=Septembre  October=Octobre  November=Novembre  December=Décembre


${day_of_week}=  Convert Date   ${next_week}  result_format=%A
${day_of_week_fr}=  Get From Dictionary  ${day_of_week_collections}  ${day_of_week}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the French result using the [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/locale.html) library in python:

```
Evaluate    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'french')    locale
${today}=    Get Time
${today_s}=    Convert Date    ${today}    result_format=%A %d %B
```

If you want 1st uppercase add this:

```
${today_s}=  Evaluate  """${today_s}""".title()
```

Comment: How to uppercase the 1st lettrer?  `mercredi` => `Mercredi`

Comment: In French apparently the [days and months](https://www.thoughtco.com/use-of-french-capitalization-4085543) are not normally capitalized which is what the locale setting is adhering too. The best solution I can think of is to call: `Evaluate       """${today_s}""".title()` but then both days and months will be capitalized